# "iex -S mix" returns error server cannot start in Mac

Tags: macos, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-iex

I was trying to start up my mix project in elixir on Mac. The project works fine on CentOS.
The error looks like this:

```
_build/dev/lib/<project_name>/ebin/Elixir.Mix.Tasks.Proddata.beam failed: :badfile
** (Mix) Could not start application exq: Exq.start(:normal, []) returned an error:
  shutdown: failed to start child: Exq.Manager
    ** (EXIT) {:connection_error, {:connection_error, :econnrefused}}
```

I tried updating my erlang version from brew, but it did not help. I have also tried cleaning dependencies. I am using

```
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]
```

and Elixir 1.0.5.

Comment: Try removing the entire _build directory tree and recompiling.

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog tried that, did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the errors:

> _build/dev/lib//ebin/Elixir.Mix.Tasks.Proddata.beam failed: :badfile

This one means you are trying to invoke a task with the wrong name. Maybe you are calling "mix run proddata" and that will look for the task named Proddata but you may have named it differently. Use `mix help` to see which tasks are available.

> ** (Mix) Could not start application exq: Exq.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Exq.Manager
>         ** (EXIT) {:connection_error, {:connection_error, :econnrefused}}

It it saying it cannot connect to *something*. It seems that `Exq.Manager` needs Redis, so make sure Redis is running and you have configured it with the proper credentials.

Comment: Hey jose, the connection was failing to redis, it works now. I am not sure why the "Proddata" is being used, everything is working for now.